# Is a substitution of variable a linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra

I've been asking myself this. A linear transformation $T:U \rightarrow V$ between the vector spaces $U$ and $V$ is a function that respects the following:

a) $T(x+y) = T(x)+T(y) $  $ \forall x,y \in U$

b) $T(\alpha x) = \alpha T(x) $   $\forall \alpha \in K, x \in U$, where $K$ is the scalar field of $U$ and $V$.

So consider a substitution of variables from a cubic equation $t^{3} + at^{2}+ct+d=0$, where $t = \frac{y-a}{3}$. Is it a linear transformation? I write $T(t) = \frac{y-a}{3}$, but $y$ depends on $t$, so I don't know how to calculate $T(t_{1} + t_{2})$ or $T(\alpha t)$.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the rule of $T$ here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you want is the transformation 
$$ T(p(t))=p\left(\frac{t-a}{3}\right)$$
from the space of polynomials (over a given scalar field) to itself.
Given two polynomials $p_1$ and $p_2$, we have
$$T((p_1+p_2)(t))=(p_1+p_2)\left(\frac{t-a}{3}\right)=p_1\left(\frac{t-a}{3}\right)+p_2\left(\frac{t-a}{3}\right)=T(p_1(t))+T(p_2(t)). $$
Now let $p$ be a polynomial, and let $\alpha$ be a scalar.  We have
$$T((\alpha p)(t))=(\alpha p)\left(\frac{t-a}{3}\right)=\alpha p\left(\frac{t-a}{3}\right)=\alpha T(p(t)).$$
Therefore, $T$ is linear.

Is this what you were looking for?